# Error with running ASP Web application in Mac

Tags: asp.net, macos, libc, dnx, libuv

I have created Web application in Mac OS and able to build it.
On dnx web i get the following error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: libc.dylib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.IO.KeventWatcher:kqueue ()
  at System.IO.KeventWatcher.GetInstance (IFileWatcher& watcher) <0x105a29310 + 0x000f3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.InitWatcher () <0x105a28fa0 + 0x0012c> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher..ctor (System.String path, System.String filter) <0x105a28d00 + 0x00114> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher..ctor (System.String path) <0x105a28cc0 + 0x00023> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileSystemWatcher:.ctor (string)
  at Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.PhysicalFilesWatcher..ctor (System.String root) <0x105a285b0 + 0x00154> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor (System.String root) <0x105a282d0 + 0x000e4> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentExtensions.Initialize (IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, System.String applicationBasePath, IConfiguration config) <0x105a27f20 + 0x001ea> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build () <0x105a1a860 + 0x000b8> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WebApplication.Run (System.Type startupType, System.String[] args) <0x105560990 + 0x00216> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WebApplication.Run (System.String[] args) <0x10555fef0 + 0x0001a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Program.Main (System.String[] args) <0x10555fec0 + 0x00014> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Program.Main (System.String[] args) <0x10555fc90 + 0x000b5> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) <0x1050027a0 + 0x000b7> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ExecuteMain>b__0 () in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () in <filename unknown>:line 0
Unhandled Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.Stop () in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.Finalize () in <filename unknown>:line 0
```

I have tried the suggestion in the below question 
[dnx kestrel "System.EntryPointNotFoundException: uv_loop_size"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847375/dnx-kestrel-system-entrypointnotfoundexception-uv-loop-size/33883189#33883189) 
and set DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH.

Yet unable to resolve the issue. Any ideas to resolve it.

Comment: In Terminal what is the output of `echo $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: l'L'l output - ~/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/local/lib:/Users/labuser/.dnx/packages

Comment: It looks like you're missing `/usr/lib` in your path.

Comment: @I'L'l  where do i miss /usr/lib?

Comment: It's not in the output result!  you have `~/lib`, `/usr/local/lib` (twice), `/lib`, and your `libuv` directory...

Comment: @l'L'l I set path as follows.  $DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="~/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/local/lib" and $export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/Users/labuser/.dnx/packages". Is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're putting things in there twice and still leaving out `/usr/lib`.

Comment: @ l'L'l - i have added /usr/lib in my path. Now echo path returns -~/lib:/usr/local/lib:/Users/labuser/.dnx/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel/1.0.0-rc1-final/runtimes/osx:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib. But i get error on dnx web command `System.EntryPointNotFoundException: uv_loop_size
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv+NativeDarwinMonoMethods:uv_loop_size ()`